# Is there any easy way to add serial key input text field in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield

I'd like to add a text field by Extjs to let user input serial number, the text field should looks like:
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
Is there any easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Im doing it mannually under listeners

```
'change': function(textfield,newValue,oldValue){
    var value = textfield.getValue();
    value = value.toString();
    value = value.split("-").join("");
    if (value.length > 0) {
       value = value.match(new RegExp('.{1,5}', 'g')).join("-");
    }
 }
```